# Spring Cloud application fails to connect to AWS Kinesis 'dynamoDBClient' must not be null

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-aws

**Unable to connect to Kinesis stream using Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis binder due to error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dynamoDBClient' must not be null**

//Stream binding

```
EnableBinding(DataStream.class)
public class StreamsConfig {}
```

//Stream config

```
 public interface DataStream {
 
    String AUDIT_IN = "auditIn";

    @Input(AUDIT_IN)
    SubscribableChannel auditIn();
 }
```

//Stream Listener

```
 @StreamListener(DataStream.AUDIT_IN)
    public void processAudit(finalAuditMessage auditMessage) {
     logger.info("Received audit message : {}", auditMessage);
     MDCUtil.setContext(auditMessage.getTenantId(), null, null);
     persistAuditMessage(auditMessage);
     MDCUtil.clearContext();
 }
```

Application.yaml

```
  cloud:
    aws:
      stack:
        auto: false
      region:
        static: us-west-2
      credentials:
        useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain: true

  management:
    context-path: /actuator
    security:
      enabled: false
      roles: ADMIN

    endpoint:
      metrics:
        enabled: true
      loggers:
        enabled: true
      health:
        show-details: always

    endpoints:
      web:
        exposure:
          include: "health,metrics,info,loggers"

    metrics:
      export:
        statsd:
          enabled: true
          flavor: telegraf
          host: telegraf-s.cluster-services.svc.cluster.local
          port: 8125
      tags:
        service: audit
        namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}

      distribution:
        percentiles:
          http:
            server:
              requests: 0.5,0.9,0.99

        percentiles-histogram:
          http:
            server:
              requests: true

  logging:
    level:
      org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
      org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE


  spring:
    application:
      name: audit
    zipkin:
      enabled: false
    cloud:
      stream:
        bindings:
          auditIn:
            content-type: application/json
            destination: ***
            consumer:
              describeStreamRetries: 10
            group: ***

        kinesis:
          binder:
            autoCreateStream: true
            autoAddShards: false
            kplKclEnabled: true

      vault:
        token: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        ssl:
          trust-store: ***
          trust-store-password: ***
        generic:
          enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 8200
        scheme: https
        connection:
          timeout: 5000
        read-timeout: 15000
        authentication: KUBERNETES
        kubernetes:
          role: owner
          kubernetes-path: kubernetes
          service-account-token-file: token
        kv:
          enabled: false
          backend: kv-v2
          application-name: configuration/mysql

    jpa:
      open-in-view: false

  audit:
    filter:
      block:
        methods: GET
```

Debug log

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: osx
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: osx-x86_64
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------< com.nile:audit >---------------------------
[INFO] Building audit 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ audit >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ audit ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ audit ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ audit ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ audit ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ audit <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ audit ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/Users/arvindkgs/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-02-24 20:40:38,529 ERROR [main] com.nile.cloudutilities.audit.aspect.MethodMap                [] [] - STARTING AUDIT BUILD AT 2021-02-24T15:10:38.524052Z
2021-02-24 20:40:39,984 ERROR [main] com.nile.cloudutilities.audit.aspect.MethodMap                [] [] - FINISHED AUDIT BUILD AT 2021-02-24T15:10:39.984543Z: 3/14/0 (0 mappings)
Running custom WebSecurity
2021-02-24 20:40:52,203 DEBUG [main] org.hibernate.SQL                                             [] [] - select loggerconf0_.id as id1_2_, loggerconf0_.create_time as create_t2_2_, loggerconf0_.last_update as last_upd3_2_, loggerconf0_.configuration as configur4_2_, loggerconf0_.service as service5_2_ from logger_configs loggerconf0_ where loggerconf0_.service=?
2021-02-24 20:40:52,219 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder                 [] [] - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [audit]
2021-02-24 20:40:54,068 ERROR [main] org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService       [] [] - Failed to create consumer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer:
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:471) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindConsumer(BindingService.java:169) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:126) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:112) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle$$Lambda$1628/000000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) [?:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) [spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.nile.audit.AuditService.main(AuditService.java:60) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dynamoDBClient' must not be null.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.<init>(KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:143) ~[spring-integration-aws-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder.createKclConsumerEndpoint(KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:314) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:291) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:417) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
2021-02-24 20:40:54,167 DEBUG [main] org.hibernate.SQL                                             [] [] - select loggerconf0_.id as id1_2_, loggerconf0_.create_time as create_t2_2_, loggerconf0_.last_update as last_upd3_2_, loggerconf0_.configuration as configur4_2_, loggerconf0_.service as service5_2_ from logger_configs loggerconf0_ where loggerconf0_.service=?
2021-02-24 20:40:54,169 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder                 [] [] - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [audit]
^C[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  49.955 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-24T20:40:58+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "nexus" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

pom.xml - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kBEj6HqTQS5BgA7StaFZBEKfbLrpgSMR/view?usp=sharing

Using following jars

```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.11.655:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-producer:jar:0.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-aws:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-core:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.415:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.415:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:dynamodb-lock-client:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter:jar:1.5.0:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with Spring BOOT apps and AWS APIs, try using the official AWS SDK for Java V2 API (as opposed to non Amazon APIs). *Amazon recommends moving from V1 to V2*.

Here is an example that does use DynamoDB API V2 within a Spring BOOT application. This use case lets a user submit data from a simple web form and then the data is stored in an Amazon DynamoDB table. Then it shows you how to use SNS to fire off a text message. In addition, this shows you how to successfully use AWS Java V2 APIs within a Spring Boot app.

Once its written, this shows you how to deploy the Spring Boot App to the cloud:

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

Once you get a basic Spring app working with AWS Java V2 APIs, you can use other services.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was creating a DynamoDBClient bean that returned null. This bean is autowired in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.KinesisMessageChannelBinder.